# Evaluate an expression binary tree - Daily Coding Challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, expression-trees

Here is my solution for the Daily Coding Challenge 50

> Given an arithmetic expression in the form of a binary tree, write a function to evaluate it

**Example**

```
    *
   / \
  +    +
 / \  / \
3  2  4  5

Return >> 45
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

```
"""Build an operation tree and calculate the result"""


class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        """Initialise values"""
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def determine_sum(self, total):
        if self.left == None and self.right == None:
            return int(self.value)
        if self.value == "*":
            total += self.left.determine_sum(total) * self.right.determine_sum(total)
        if self.value == "+":
            total += self.left.determine_sum(total) + self.right.determine_sum(total)
        if self.value == "-":
            total += self.left.determine_sum(total) - self.right.determine_sum(total)
        if self.value == "/":
            total += self.left.determine_sum(total) / self.right.determine_sum(total)
        return total


if __name__ == "__main__":  #
    n = Tree("*")
    n.left = Tree("+")
    n.right = Tree("+")
    n.left.right = Tree("+")
    n.right.right = Tree("+")

    n.left.left = Tree("3")
    n.left.right.left = Tree("4")
    n.left.right.right = Tree("5")

    n.right.left = Tree("6")
    n.right.right.left = Tree("7")
    n.right.right.right = Tree("4")

    sum = n.determine_sum(0)
    print(sum)
```

Comment: In what sense is this a [binary _search_ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)?

Comment: Sorry. Binary tree. My apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `dict` > `if`s
- [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html) contains all the functions you need.
- Taking `total` as an argument is unneeded.
- I would personally split the 'Tree' which is actually a Node into two types, operators and values. But that may go against the challenge.
- Use `is` to compare to `None`.

```
import operator

operators = {
    '*': operator.mul,
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '/': operator.truediv,
}


class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        """Initialise values"""
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def determine(self):
        if self.left is None and self.right is None:
            return int(self.value)

        return operators[self.value](
            self.left.determine(),
            self.right.determine()
        )
```

Comment: You never fail to amaze with with how succinctly you write code. Thanks

Comment: @EML With time you'll be able to too :) You'll be able to see common pitfalls that you know how to fix without even thinking.